# Populating multiple Excel spreadsheets from a text file

Tags: excel

I need to populate a new spreadsheet for every 26 rows in a text file. I have created the initial spreadsheet but get the error System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException:Exception from HRESULT:0x800401A8 when it starts the second file creation.

Comment: You may have closed the Workbook and quitted the App in the `foor` loop and not after it. You cannot access a variable in a workbook that isn't open anymore. Check if the workbook is actually really open.

Comment: Thanks Usama spot on, issue resolved.